# In SpringBatch how do I persist data to multiple tables from one .csv file

Tags: java

Hope someone can help me.
I have no previous experience with springbatch. I am using it for the first time.
I have one .csv file and need to persist its data  into three different tables in a SqlServer database with SpringBatch. It seems to me that it is not possible to do that. Springbatch can't persist into multiple tables from one .csv file read. I've been browsing the internet for a solution and examples but found nothing so far.
Can someone more experienced tell me whether it is possible or not. If so, Can send me any example with a solution, please.
Thank you all.

Comment: And why wouldn't that be possible? You can simply write an `ItemWriter` that does just that.

Comment: M. Dinum, thanks in advance but I tried just that, could you show me any simple example on how you would do it?

Comment: Inject a `JdbcTemplate` execute X insert statements (1 per table). Not sure how that can be complex.